# SQL statement for column value that matches both regex

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, rlike

The table "article" has a cloumn named "A_Title". I want to select the A_Title that matches **exactly** both `/[A-Za-z]+/` and `/[\x{0981}-\x{09E3}]/u` regex at the same time.

I tried several methods for it, but neither is working. Giving error: #1139 - Got error 'invalid character range' from regexp

```
SELECT A_Title FROM article WHERE A_Title REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+.*[\x{0981}-\x{09E3}]|[\x{0981}-\x{09E3}].*[A-Za-z]+'

SELECT A_Title FROM article WHERE A_Title REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+.*[\\x{0981}-\\x{09E3}]|[\\x{0981}-\\x{09E3}].*[A-Za-z]+'
```

Below code works, but it is not using the same regex:

```
SELECT A_Title FROM article WHERE A_Title RLIKE '[A-Za-z]+.*[ঀ-৳]|[ঀ-৳].*[A-Za-z]+'
```

Comment: @Tushar #1139 - Got error 'invalid character range' from regexp

Comment: @Tushar Doesn't work, I already have this SQL statement in my question mentioning - "Not working"

Comment: Hi @Rains, could you specify what DB engine you are testing on? special character could be a bit dffierent in different DB engines.

Comment: I'm testing on the MySQL engine

Comment: Thanks for updating the DB engine.
In Mysql; The following shall work :

`SELECT A_Title FROM article WHERE A_Title REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+.*[\\u0981-\\u09E3]|[\\u0981-\\u09E3].*[A-Za-z]+';`

Can you tell me if you still face any issues ?

Comment: @Tushar no it does not. I'm requesting you to read my question again.

Comment: @Tushar I want both REGEX at the same.

Comment: Yes; I read it again. 
I also understand from your working regexp that you are using this for comparing `Bangla` characters.  For MySQL regex;
`\x{0981}` this syntax is incorrect; So, I just removed the `x` from it in my above solution.

Can you use it as :
`SELECT A_Title FROM article WHERE A_Title REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+.*[\u0981-\u09E3]|[\u0981-\u09E3].*[A-Za-z]+';`

and let me know

Comment: "exactly both" ???  Please provide a few samples that should match _and a few that should _not_ match.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL regex; `\x{0981}` this syntax is incorrect; So, just remove the x from it in your regexp.

and then you can combine these both REGEXP statements the same way you have written your working regexp in the post :

```
SELECT A_Title FROM article WHERE A_Title REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+.*[\\u0981-\\u09E3]|[\\u0981-\\u09E3].*[A-Za-z]+';
```

As you have already tagged `RLIKE` in your post; you can even use it instead of `REGEXP` as [REGEXP and RLIKE are synonyms for REGEXP_LIKE() synonym of REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).